# 5*2=55 not 10! Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to output 5 * 2 = 10 but python output is 55!
How do I resolve this problem?

```
a = 0
b = 2

a = input("a? :") #(get 5 as input)

c = a * b

print (c)
```

This is my code.
when I input a number it repeat same number I entered two times insterd of showing multipiy it. What do I have to do to solve this?

Comment: "5" * 2 == "55", 5 * 2 == 10. Your 5 is really a string, not an int.

Comment: Try this: `print(repr(c))` and see that c is a string, not int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is a string,

so it will be

```
'5'*2='55'
```

if you want 10, you need to cast a to int.

```
a=int(input())
```

here is the link to document

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input